# o mysql query browser ou mysql workbench são SGBD?

Tags: banco-de-dados

queria saber se esses dois programas sao SGBD por favor pra colocar num trabalho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O MySQL Server é um Sistema Gerenciador de Banco de Dados (SGBD). O Workbench é uma ferramenta visual para controle das funcionalidades do servidor. O Workbench só funcionará caso o MySQL Server estiver devidamente instalado. O mesmo vale para o Query Browser.